# Incorrect results from code written for basic Java exercise

Tags: java

Here are the instructions

> Online Book Depot offers premium customers 1 free book with every purchase of 5 or more books and offers 2 free books with every purchase of 8 or more books.
>
> It offers regular customers 1 free book with every purchase of 7 or more books, and offers 2 free books with every purchase of 12 or more books.
>
> Write the block of code that assigns freeBooks the appropriate value based on the values of the boolean variable isPremiumCustomer and the int variable nbooksPurchased

The code compiles without error but results are incorrect:

```
boolean isPremiumCustomer = false;
    int freeBooks = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the no of books:");
    int nbooksPurchased = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("is Premium customer?(y/n):");
    String ans = scanner.next();
    if (ans.equals("y") || ans.equals("Y") && (nbooksPurchased >4 && (nbooksPurchased <8))) {
        isPremiumCustomer = true;
        freeBooks = 1;
    }else if (ans.equals("y") || ans.equals("Y") && (nbooksPurchased >=8 )) {
        isPremiumCustomer = true;
        freeBooks = 2;
    }else if (ans.equals("n") || ans.equals("N") && (nbooksPurchased >=7 && (nbooksPurchased <=11))) {
        freeBooks = 1;
    }else if (ans.equals("n") || ans.equals("N") && (nbooksPurchased >=12 )){
        freeBooks = 2;
        }
        System.out.println("Free Books:" + freeBooks);
```

Comment: Define *"results are incorrect"*. What are the inputs and (incorrect) outputs. Also you should first try to step through it using a debugger. Finally I would recommend you to try to change the flow a bit - isolate the check of input from the check of `nbooksPurchased`

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code to see where things go different from what you expected?

Comment: What is the result you expected? and What is the result you get?

Comment: Sorry guys like I said very new....not covered debugging on courses yet! An example input/ouput:    Input - "24" and "Y"   the expected output should be "2" but its comes back as "1"

Comment: You should separate the code that assigns the isPremiumCustomer variable from the code assigning to the freebooks variable. It's muddling up you logic

Comment: ((ans.equals("y") || ans.equals("Y"))  use parenthesis on every OR condition.

Comment: Try not to do everything in one long if-else construct, that gets more complicated than needed. Try one if statement to set `isPremiumCustomer` to true if this is a premium customer. Next do one if-else with just `if (isPremiumCustomer) {` … Inside each part of this if-else put a new but shorter if-else construct to set `freeBooks` to the correct value. Yes, you can put if-else inside another if-else; if only you keep your indentation nice, it shouldn’t be too hard to grasp.

Comment: @FarazSultan is correct: `ans.equals("y") || ans.equals("Y") && (nbooksPurchased >4 && (nbooksPurchased <8))` will be evaluated the same as `ans.equals("y") || (ans.equals("Y") && nbooksPurchased >4 && nbooksPurchased < 8)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: This is driving me nuts...`if (ans.equals("y") || ans.equals("Y")) {
            isPremiumCustomer = true;
        }
        if (nbooksPurchased >= 3 && (nbooksPurchased <= 7)) {
            freeBooks = 1;
        } else if (nbooksPurchased >= 8) {
            freeBooks = 2;
        }
        if (ans.equals("n") || ans.equals("N")) {
            if ((nbooksPurchased >= 7 && (nbooksPurchased <= 11))) {
                freeBooks = 1;
            } else if (nbooksPurchased >= 12) {
                freeBooks = 2;`

Answer (score 1):

Reading your code in the comment is hardly possible. So I formatted it and got:

```
    if (ans.equals("y") || ans.equals("Y")) {
        isPremiumCustomer = true;
    }
    if (nbooksPurchased >= 3 && (nbooksPurchased <= 7)) {
        freeBooks = 1;
    } else if (nbooksPurchased >= 8) {
        freeBooks = 2;
    }
    if (ans.equals("n") || ans.equals("N")) {
        if ((nbooksPurchased >= 7 && (nbooksPurchased <= 11))) {
            freeBooks = 1;
        } else if (nbooksPurchased >= 12) {
            freeBooks = 2;
        }
    }
```

Now you’re clearly on the way compared to your code in the question. The main problem with this is that the middle if-else construct `if (nbooksPurchased >= 3 && (nbooksPurchased <= 7)) {` is executed for all customers, not only premium customers. So regular customers that buy 3 or 6 books get the 1 free book that only premium customers should have had on such a purchase. If they buy 7 or more, the execution gets into `if (ans.equals("n") || ans.equals("N")) {`, and you’re saved.

The other problem is just a typo, `nbooksPurchased >= 3` should have been 5 for premium customers.

So I believe most cases work correctly.

I think that this would be clearer (and hence easier for yourself to correct errors in):

```
    if (isPremiumCustomer) {
        // put if-else for premium customers here
    } else {
        // put if-else for regular customers here
    }
```

Also I think this will better fulfil the requirement:

> Write the block of code that assigns freeBooks the appropriate value
> *based on* the values of the boolean variable isPremiumCustomer and …

(my emphasis).